# How to select an element with find statment?

Tags: jquery, html

I need to fill `select` element with `json` data but I can't select target element right now. I have not any error in console . What could be the issue?

**jQuery:**

```
$('#accordion1 select[name$=Tarrif]').change(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Train/TrianFood',
        data: { Tarrif: $(this).val() },
        type: "POST",
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.Result == false) {        
                for (var i = 0; i <result.obj.length; i++) {
                    $(this).closest('.person-information').find('select[name$=Food]').empty().append(new Option(result.obj[i].ServiceType, result.obj[i].ServiceTypeCode));
                }
            } else {
                $(this).closest('.person-information').find('select[name$=Food]').empty().append(new Option('بدون غذا', 1));
            }    
        },
        error: function () { }
    });
    //-------------
});

<div class="panel style1">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a href="#acc@(j)" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1">مسافر @(j + 1) </a>
    </h4>
    <div class="panel-collapse collapse @if(j==0) {<text> in </text>}" id="acc@(j)">
        <div class="panel-content">
            <div class="person-information">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-8">
                        <label>نام </label>
                        <input type="text" name="[@(j)].FirstName" class="input-text full-width" lang="fa-IR" data-val="true" data-val-required="لطفا نام را وارد نمایید." />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="[@(j)].FirstName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label>نام خانوادگی</label>
                        <input type="text" name="[@(j)].LastName" class="input-text full-width" lang="fa-IR" data-val="true" data-val-required="لطفا نام خانوادگی را وارد نمایید." />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="[@(j)].LastName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-8">
                        <label>کد ملی</label>
                        <input type="text" name="[@(j)].NationalCode" class="input-text full-width" lang="fa-IR" data-val-required="لطفا کد ملی را وارد نمایید." placeholder="کد ملی 10 رقمی" data-val="true" data-val-length="کد ملی باید 10 رقمی باشد." data-val-length-max="10" data-val-length-min="10" data-val-regex="فقط عدد وارد نمایید." data-val-regex-pattern="(^[0-9']+$)" />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="[@(j)].NationalCode" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 datepicker-wrap">
                        <label>تاریخ تولد</label>
                        <input type="text" name="[@(j)].DateOfbirth" autocomplete="off" class="input-text full-width" placeholder="--/--/----" data-val="true" data-val-required="لطفا تاریخ تولد را وارد نمائید." />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="[@(j)].DateOfbirth" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-4">
                        <label>جنسیت</label>
                        <div class="selector">
                            <select class="full-width" name="[@(j)].SexCode">
                                <option value="1">مرد</option>
                                <option value="2">زن</option>
                                <option value="3">خانواده</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4  col-md-pull-4">
                        <label>نوع مسافر</label>
                        <div class="selector">
                            <select class="full-width" name="[@(j)].Tarrif">
                                @if (TempData["Tarrif"] != null) {                                                                 List<GetAgentAllowedTarrif> lists = new List<GetAgentAllowedTarrif>();
                                    lists = (List<GetAgentAllowedTarrif>)TempData["Tarrif"];
                                    foreach (var item in lists) {
                                        <option value="@item.FTariffCode"> @item.TarriffName</option>
                                    }
                                }
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 pull-right">
                        <label>غذا</label>
                        <div class="selector">
                            <select class="full-width" name="[@(j)].Food">
                                <option>بدون 1</option>
                                <option value="2">بدون 2</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(this)` is different inside ajax what error you get

Comment: I have not any error in console..

Comment: `$(this)` is not what you think. That has to be cached or use `context` in the Ajax's options.

Comment: Try this,   store `this` into `current` variable before AJAX request and then replace `this` with `current` below AJAX

Comment: have var `thiscontext = $(this)` before ajax and use `thiscontext.closest('.person-information').find('select[name$=Food]').empty().append(new Option(result.obj[i].ServiceType, result.obj[i].ServiceTypeCode));`

Comment: Pass as ajax option: `context: this,`

Comment: OK.Thank you .It solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

Store `this` into `current` variable before call to `AJAX` request and then replace `this` which you have written inside `success` block with `current`

May this will help you..

Comment: The widely used conventions are `var self = this` or `var $this = $(this)` before another function body.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#accordion1 select[name$=Tarrif]').change(function () {
    var this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Train/TrianFood',
        data: { Tarrif: this.val() },
        type: "POST",
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.Result == false) {
                for (var i = 0; i <result.obj.length; i++) {
                    this.closest('.person-information').find('select[name$=Food]').empty().append(new Option(result.obj[i].ServiceType, result.obj[i].ServiceTypeCode));
                }
            } else {
                this.closest('.person-information').find('select[name$=Food]').empty().append(new Option('بدون غذا', 1));
            }
        },
        error: function () { }
    });
});
```